# Spring cloud config server not able to read property file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

My Spring cloud config server is throwing below error when trying to access the property file content using http://localhost:8080/application/default

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not construct context for config=application profile=default label= includeOrigin=false; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ConfigFileApplicationListener [org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener] is deprecated and can only be used as an EnvironmentPostProcessor
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.FailedToConstructEnvironmentException: Could not construct context for config=application profile=default label= includeOrigin=false; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ConfigFileApplicationListener [org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener] is deprecated and can only be used as an EnvironmentPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:59)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:187)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.getEnvironment(EnvironmentController.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

My application.properties in config server looks like this

`spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=/Users/joe/MyProgs/Java/spring-ws/config` and I even tried with this `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${HOME}/MyProgs/Java/spring-ws/config`

Content of the property file in the local git repository is

```
martin:
    name: Martin D'vloper
    job: Developer
    skill: Elite
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this deprecation message was added just a couple of weeks ago in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22497). These changes are not even released yet (marked for release in a future milestone version of Spring Boot 2.4.0-M2).

What version of Spring Boot are you using? I suppose you have a `SNAPSHOT` dependency somewhere in your build configuration.

Comment: I was using 2.4.0(SNAPSHOT). Now I have changed it to 2.1.16 RELEASE version and it is working fine. Thanks